# Stripe appears to create popup window but closes it on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe Checkout and everything is working ok with the popup on desktop. When I view the website on mobile (specifically Chrome on vanilla Android 4.3, also tried on Opera for Android with similar result), a popup window appears to open for a brief second but then closes. I never see it and it's not in another open tab either.

I've read [this documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-more-runloop) and my code is compliant.

Here's the JavaScript I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //The actual giving part
    $('a.payamount').click(function(e) {

        window.amountToGive = $(this).data('amount');

        // Open Stripe Checkout with further options
        stripeHandler.open({
            name: campaignName,
            description: 'Give $' + (window.amountToGive / 100) + ' to ' + campaignName,
            amount: window.amountToGive
        });
    });

    var stripeHandler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: 'mykeygoeshere',
        image: '/img/g.png',
        locale: 'auto',
        token: function(token) {
            //Add campaign info
            token['campaign_id'] = campaignId;
            token['amount'] = window.amountToGive;

            postStripeData(token);
        }
    });

    // Close Checkout on page navigation
    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
        stripeHandler.close();
    });
});

function postStripeData(token) {
    showLoadingModal();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: postStripeDataUrl,
        data: token
    })
    .always(function(data_jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR_errorThrown) {
        if (textStatus.indexOf('error') == -1) {
            //POST'ed ok
            console.log(data_jqXHR);
            window.location.href = data_jqXHR;
        } else {
            alert('Error while posting!');
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using `https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js`.

I've tried debugging this via the Chrome Developer tools, in which you can see the Android logs, and no error is showing up.

Comment: Which mobile browser?

Comment: Chrome on vanilla Android 4.3

Comment: Does it work on Firefox  ? Opera? Dolphin ? stock Browser ?

Comment: There is no other browser but Chrome ;). I'll download Firefox and try.

Comment: do that, you'll know if the problem is specific to chrome.

Comment: Just tested with Opera. In this case, nothing at all appears to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good while of debugging, it seems what's missing is a `e.preventDefault();` in the click function:

```
$('a.payamount').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //... rest of code
```

Comment: @TiberiuC. Anything dangerous about this solution? Or is this FUD?

Comment: Is very well described in the article that I have shared ... If it is a FUD or not that is for you to decide